# Are Pell solutions "unique"??

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Given the Pell equation
$$X^2-2Y^2=1$$
and two solutions $(x_j,2uv)$ and $(x_k,2ac)$, with $uv=ac$ and $\gcd(u,v)=\gcd(a,c)=1$ and $u>v$ and $c>a$.

Can one prove that $(u,v)=(c,a)$, and hence $j=k$?

Comment: No.  For example a solution is $X=17$, $Y=12$, and you could get this twice by taking $(u,v)=(6,1)$ and $(c,a)=(3,2)$.  However since $Y=2uv=2ac$, it will certainly be true that $x_j=\pm x_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear now that the answer is "No". For example, $(17,12)$ is a solution to $X^2-2Y^2=1$. If $2ac=2uv=12$, we could have $(c,a)=(3,2)$ and $(u,v)=(6,1)$, as mentioned by David. Then one valid solution for the $17$ would be $17=3c+4a=2u+5v$; there are, in general, many others [because $\gcd(3,2)=\gcd(6,1)=1$].

Now the interesting question, I suppose, is: If $uv=ac$ but $(u,v)\ne(c,a)$, then what do the solutions around (*i.e.,* "above" and "below") the common solution look like?

Answer (score 2):

Don't really get the part about ac and so forth.

The equation $x^2 - n y^2 = 1$ is special in that all solutions lie in a single orbit of the automorphism group of the quadratic form $x^2 - n y^2.$ Find the "fundamental solution" $u^2 - n v^2 = 1$ with minimal $v > 0,$ and choose $u > 0.$ Then, every solution to $x^2 - n y^2$ with $x,y > 0$ is the left hand column of $A^k,$ where

$$ A \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  u  &  nv  \\
   v   &  u  
\end{array} 
  \right) .
  $$

Now, in general, the automorphism group is still infinite cyclic, for any indefinite binary quadratic form. However, there may be several distinct orbits for general $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 = d,$ where $d \neq \pm 1.$

Comment: Here are all my cards on the table:

For $X^2-2Y^2 = \pm 1$, I have found [algebraically] a solution $(F(u,v),2uv)$ and another $(c,a)$, with $u>v$ and $c>a$ and $uv=ac$, such that $(c,a)$ is a solution. By this last fact and a well-known identity, $(F(a,c),2ac)$ must also be a solution.

What I'm trying to find out: Is this enough to conclude $(u,v)=(c,a)$?

Comment: Sorry, that comment implied something not necessarily true… What I meant was, $(c,a)$ being a solution to $X^2-2Y^2=\pm1$ implies that $(G(c,a),2ca)$ is also a solution [where $G(c,a)$ might or might not be distinct from $F(c,a)$, where $(F(u,v),2uv)$ is a solution].

I guess what I'm asking is: Does $uv=ac$, with $u>v$ and $a>c$, plus the fact that $2ac$ and $2uv$ are both Pell numbers force $(u,v)=(c,a)$?

Answer (score 0):

In general Pell's equation solutions are not unique because if $(x_0, y_0)$ is a solution to $x^2-Dy^2=1$, (where $D$ is a square free positive integer $>1$) then 
$$x_k+\sqrt{D}y_k =(x_0+\sqrt{D}y_0)^k$$
will be a solution to the same equation for all $k \geq 1$. Hence infinitely many solutions.